# How to store a JoinHandle in a struct for a thread that runs with itself?

Tags: multithreading, rust, borrow-checker

I need to create a thread and store the thread join handle inside the struct, but I am getting errors:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::thread;

pub struct NetworkReceiver {
    terminate_flag: AtomicBool,
    join_handle: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl NetworkReceiver {
    pub fn new() -> NetworkReceiver {
        NetworkReceiver {
            terminate_flag: AtomicBool::new(false),
            join_handle: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        self.join_handle = Some(thread::spawn(|| self.run()));
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        while !self.terminate_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    pub fn terminate(&mut self) {
        self.terminate_flag.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.join_handle` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
18 |         self.join_handle = Some(thread::spawn(|| self.run()));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ----------------------------
   |         |                       |             |  |
   |         |                       |             |  borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |         |                       |             borrow of `self.join_handle` occurs here
   |         |                       argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'static`
   |         assignment to borrowed `self.join_handle` occurs here

error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
  --> src/main.rs:18:33
   |
17 |     pub fn start(&mut self) {
   |                  ---------
   |                  |
   |                  `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
18 |         self.join_handle = Some(thread::spawn(|| self.run()));
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                 |
   |                                 `self` escapes the associated function body here
   |                                 argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Answer (score 4):

You could separate the `join_handle` from everything else inside `NetworkReceiver` like this:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
    Arc,
};

pub struct NetworkReceiver {
    terminate_flag: AtomicBool,
}
pub struct RunningNetworkReceiver {
    join_handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
    network_receiver: Arc<NetworkReceiver>,
}

impl NetworkReceiver {
    pub fn new() -> NetworkReceiver {
        let net_recv_intf = NetworkReceiver {
            terminate_flag: AtomicBool::new(false),
        };

        net_recv_intf
    }

    pub fn start(self) -> RunningNetworkReceiver {
        let network_receiver = Arc::new(self);
        let join_handle = {
            let network_receiver = network_receiver.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || network_receiver.run())
        };
        RunningNetworkReceiver {
            join_handle,
            network_receiver,
        }
    }
    pub fn run(&self) {
        while !self.terminate_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        }
    }
}
impl RunningNetworkReceiver {
    pub fn terminate(&self) {
        self.network_receiver.terminate_flag.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}
```

If you need exclusive acces to anything inside of `NetworkReceiver` after all you'd have to wrap it (or the part that needs it) in a `RwLock` or `Mutex` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

When using variables in a thread, that thread must have ownership.  This line `(thread::spawn(|| self.run());` tries to move `self` into the thread but cannot because `self` needs to outlive the function.

I beleive you'll have to wrap your NetworkReceiver within an Arc Mutex.  You could change your `NetworkReceiver::new()` to return a Arc<Mutex> and all the associated functions would change from `fn foo(&mut self)` to `fn foo(self: Arc<Self>)`